# What do the timeline annotation lines actually represent in the mongodb atlas Metrics?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently investigating a mongo incident in our Atlas cluster. I am trying to figure out why it decided to upgrade for a period of time. I know that something happened around the memory so I've been looking at the *System Memory* metric in Atlas. In the charts there are lines added that are described as *DISPLAY TIMELINE ANNOTATIONS*.

[image]

[image]

I can see one of these lines around the time of my "incident". The problem is nothing seems to explain what these lines represent? Looking on the [mongo Atlas docs](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/view-diagnostics/) it simply states:

> Directs Ops Manager to display or hide chart annotations. Chart annotations consist of colored vertical lines that indicate server events, such as a server restart or a transition in member state.

So what exactly is a "server event"? How do I find these and what do the various colours mean?

Comment: They represent an anomaly and are the causes to reach the support. Atlas is a **managed** database service so let the pros to manage it.

Comment: Well I'm investigating the cause so that I can see if there is performance tuning required. I'm not overly comfortable with my cluster costs doubling "because magic"

Comment: But that's exactly what support is for. If you are not comfortable with either cost, performance, availability etc - talk to them. You don't have access to the underlaying OS, logs, and low level diagnostic tools. Express you concerns and demand justification for the extra cost.

Comment: I don't want to get into a conversation of managed vs unmanaged. I simply want to know what these lines actually represent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I raised a support ticket with mongo to get this information. It seems it is shown on the chart but it's a bit hidden, you need to press the `i` in the top left:

[image]

[image]

- Red - Server restart
- Orange - server is now primary
- Brown server is now secondary

Comment: when it restart primary, than other primary already selected correct?